# border color is not changed

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the borderColor and titleColor synchronized. but it didn't change the border color.

How can I make `setTitleColor` func applied to the border Color?

```
func setColor(button: UIButton) {
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.fromRGB(95, 61, 196), for: .selected)
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.fromRGB(95, 61, 196).cgColor
}

@objc func handleCleaningKinds(_ sender: UIButton) {
    setColor(button: sender)
    deselectAllButtons()
    sender.isSelected = true

}

func deselectAllButtons() {
    for subView in stackView.subviews{
        if let button = subView as? UIButton {
            button.isSelected = false
            //button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`borderColor` doesn't work with `UIButton` `selectedState`, So you need to handle that by himself based on your button's current state.

So write function like this to update state:

```
func updateSelectedState(_ isSelected: Bool) {
   button.layer.borderWidth = isSelected ? 1 : 0 // If need to hide border on normal state
   button.layer.borderColor = isSelected ? UIColor.fromRGB(95, 61, 196).cgColor : UIColor.white.cgColor  // If need another color on normal state
   button.isSelected = isSelected
}
```

Then your two functions should be like this:

```
@objc func handleCleaningKinds(_ sender: UIButton) {
    deselectAllButtons()
    updateSelectedState(sender)
}

func deselectAllButtons() {
    for subView in stackView.subviews{
        if let button = subView as? UIButton {
            updateSelectedState(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Also setting color `func setColor(button: UIButton)` should not be called each time when button clicked, so you can call this function at `viewDidLoad` or **any other function, where you create buttons.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add:

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

This might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding these 2 lines?

```
button.layer.masksToBounds = false
button.clipsToBounds = true
```